# How to add login form to homepage in Magento 2.1.9?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, login, cms

I would like to know how to add the login form to the homepage in Magento 2.1.9

Answer (score 6):

Please add below code to your layout update xml part of your home page in admin panel or in your cms_index_index.xml of your theme.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
        <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/login.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>
        </container>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: @chekhovana If its help you , Please accept answer.